# Can't debug in NativeScript and android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, nativescript

I am trying to debug my project, but the debugger doesn't seem to show any of the sources. It doesn't work in the emulator nor in the phone

[image: Node debugger empty]

I buid my project with

```
tns debug android --debug-brk
```

and start the debugger on the fly with

```
tns debug android --start
```

Comment: you should use `tns debug android` instead of `tns debug android --debug-brk` and `tns debug android --start` as it described here - http://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/debugging . With `tns debug android` all source files should be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was using Chromium browser and not Google Chrome